# Multiple Distincts with Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

given the following information I have in a database table:

```
Col 1, Col2, Col3
1    , x   , G
1    , y   , H
2    , z   , J
2    , a   , K
2    , a   , K
3    , b   , E
```

What can I do in Linq (as I'm using Entity Framework) to get the following:

```
1    , x   , G
1    , y   , H
2    , z   , J
2    , a   , K
3    , b   , E
```

You get the idea, I can do it in SQL just fine with the following:

```
Select Col 1, Col 2, Col 3 
from Table
group by Col 1, Col 2, Col 3
```

No Idea how to do it in code as I can only find a way to do a distinct on one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
var Result = Context.Table.Select(C => 
                     new { 
                           Col1 = C.Col1, 
                           Col2 = C.Col2, 
                           Col3 = C.Col3 }).Distinct();
```

Or alternately :

```
var Result = Context.Table.GroupBy(G=> new { G.Col1, G.Col2, G.Col3 })
                           .Select(C => new { 
                                             Col1 = C.Key.Col1, 
                                             Col2 = C.Key.Col2, 
                                             Col3 = C.Key.Col3 
                                            });
```

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, I am not aware about this coz i was busy with my editing although its not exact same to your answer.

Comment: Yes now I see your edit happened 1 minute after my answer, so it's yours.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use group by in linq on multiple fields:

```
myList.GroupBy(x=>new {x.Col1,x.Col2,x.Col3}).Select(x=>x.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: My table has 1 million records, distinct on all columns is taking lot of time, how to improve the performance?

Answer (score 1):

It is simple as, if you have only these three columns in the table.

```
var result = Context.Table.Distinct();
```

This will return your desired result.

If you have more columns then you can try as `@Saeed Amiri` stated in his answer.

`@Kundan Singh Chouhan's` alternative will give you the exact same sql query, which you state in your question